# How to avoid TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I am currently getting the error TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable because I am using % to divide by a float number. This is my code:

```
def displayBalance(name,ID):
    with sqlite3.connect("ATM.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select Balance from Atm where CustomerID=?",(ID,))
        balance = cursor.fetchone()

        newBalance = int(balance[0][0]) % 10
        print(newBalance)
```

Now, I am trying to use the % divide button with the balance I have stored for that user. The amount is obviously a real or float number, however I can't figure out how I can bypass this TypeError. Any ideas?

Comment: `int(balance[0][0]) % 10` => int(balance[0]) % 10

Comment: Knew it was something obvious. Thanks Jean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
balance = cursor.fetchone()
```

returns a `tuple` with the requested values. In your case, you're asking for 1 value, so `balance` is a tuple containing 1 sole value, access using `[0]`:

```
newBalance = int(balance[0]) % 10
```

else python tries to "subscript" the value (i.e. access by index), which isn't valid.

Alternately, you can *unpack* your value directly like this:

```
    (balance,) = cursor.fetchone()
```

then:

```
    newBalance = int(balance) % 10
```